# How do I take 2 sorted lists and add them to another list while removing the elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have lists

```
a=[1,3,6,9,10]
b=[2,4,5,7,8]
c=[]
```

How do I add the lists to list c while removing the elements from a and b?

Comment: c=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
sorry just edited it to make it better

Comment: Oh your edit changed the source lists quite a bit.

Comment: Do you NEED to have `a = b = []` afterwards?

Comment: if you mean a=[] and b=[]
yes!

Comment: `c, a, b = sorted(a + b), [], []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c = []

aa, bb = a.pop(0), b.pop(0)
while True:
    if aa < bb:
        c.append(aa)
        try:
            aa = a.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            c += b
            b = []
    else:
        c.append(bb)
        try:
            bb = b.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            c += a
            a = []
```

Or

```
c = sorted(a + b)
a = b = []
```